# Calculate gradients of variables used in assignment of other variable using tf.GradientTape

Tags: tensorflow, variables, tensorflow2.0, gradient, gradienttape

How can one calculate the gradient on a variable with respect to another variable used in a linear combination? The following code is executed in TensorFlow eager mode.

Some more digging in older questions, a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48242688/19087072) showed up. However, it is not clear on how to solve this issue.
Another related question is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44352654/19087072), but here the same variable is reused and `TensorFlow v1`.

I also read in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59562683/19087072) that `tf.assign` (v1?) does not support gradients and a potential solution is provided there.
However, I'd apply it in context of internal model weights of neural networks, but I don't know how to apply that tensor-approach in practice.

```
a = tf.Variable(1.0, name='a')
b = tf.Variable(2.0, name='b')
c = tf.Variable(3.0, name='c')

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  c.assign(a + b)
  loss = tf.reduce_mean(c**2)

print(tape.gradient(loss, b)) # prints None

# or another attempt
with tf.GradientTape(watch_accessed_variables=False) as tape:
   tape.watch([b,c])
   c.assign(a + b)
   loss = tf.reduce_mean(c**2)

print(tape.gradient(loss, b)) # also outputs None

# Working, but c is a variable in my use case
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
   c = a + b
   loss = tf.reduce_mean(c**2)

print(tape.gradient(loss, b)) # Works
```

Extension:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
a = [tf.Variable(1.0, name='a'), tf.Variable(4.0, name='aa')]
b = [tf.Variable(2.0, name='b'), tf.Variable(9.0, name='bb')]
c = [tf.Variable(3.0, name='c'), tf.Variable(0.0, name='cc')]
x = tf.Variable(0.01)

with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
    c_ = tf.nest.map_structure(lambda _a, _b: (1-x)*_a+ x*_b, a, b)
    tf.nest.map_structure(lambda x, y: x.assign(y), c, c_)
    loss = tf.norm(c) # scalar

# This works as expected
print(tape.gradient(loss,c,output_gradients=tape.gradient(c_,b)))
# [<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.0024197185>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.009702832>]
# Here I would expect a 1D gradient to use the Gradient Descent method?
print(tape.gradient(loss,c,output_gradients=tape.gradient(c_,x)))
# [<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=1.4518311>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=5.8216996>]

# Example what I'd like to achieve;
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  c_ = tf.nest.map_structure(lambda _a, _b: (1-x)*_a+ x*_b, a, b)
  loss = tf.norm(c_) # scalar

print(tape.gradient(loss,x)) 
# tf.Tensor(5.0933886, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

A more sophisticated issue:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

a = [tf.Variable([1.0, 2.0], name='a'), tf.Variable([5.0], name='aa'), tf.Variable(7.0, name='aaa')]
b = [tf.Variable([3.0, 4.0], name='b'), tf.Variable([6.0], name='bb'), tf.Variable(8.0, name='aaa')]
c = [tf.Variable([1.0, 1.0], name='c'), tf.Variable([1.0], name='cc'), tf.Variable(1.0, name='ccc')]
x = tf.Variable(0.5, name='x')

with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
    c_ = tf.nest.map_structure(lambda _a, _b: (1-x)*_a+ x*_b, a, b)

    tf.nest.map_structure(lambda x, y: x.assign(y), c, c_)

    loss = tf.norm(tf.nest.map_structure(lambda e: tf.norm(e), c))
    loss_without_assign = tf.norm(tf.nest.map_structure(lambda e: tf.norm(e), c_))

print(loss, loss_without_assign)
# tf.Tensor(9.974969, shape=(), dtype=float32) tf.Tensor(9.974969, shape=(), dtype=float32)

# Gives same result
#partial_grads = tf.nest.map_structure(lambda d, e: tf.nest.map_structure(lambda f, g: tape.gradient(loss, f, output_gradients=tape.gradient(g, x)), d, e), c, c_)
partial_grads = tf.nest.map_structure(lambda d, e: tape.gradient(loss, d, output_gradients=tape.gradient(e, x)), c, c_)

# Should not use mean?
print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.nest.map_structure(lambda z: tf.reduce_mean(z), partial_grads)))
print(tape.gradient(loss_without_assign, x))
# Rather close
# tf.Tensor(2.3057716, shape=(), dtype=float32)
# tf.Tensor(2.3057709, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try as following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.Variable(1.0, name='a')
b = tf.Variable(2.0, name='b')
c = tf.Variable(3.0, name='c')

with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
  c_ = a + 2*b
  c.assign(c_)
  loss = tf.reduce_mean(c**2)

print(tape.gradient(loss,c,output_gradients=tape.gradient(c_,b))) 
# tf.Tensor(20.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

P.S. `output_gradients` is a parameter of `tf.GradientTape.gradient` that hidden in the corner and rarely found, which can be used to manually build cascade differentiation.

- For Extension:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
a = [tf.Variable(1.0, name='a'), tf.Variable(4.0, name='aa')]
b = [tf.Variable(2.0, name='b'), tf.Variable(9.0, name='bb')]
c = [tf.Variable(3.0, name='c'), tf.Variable(0.0, name='cc')]
x = tf.Variable(0.0, name='x')

with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
    c_ = tf.nest.map_structure(lambda _a, _b: (1-x)*_a+ x*_b, a, b)
    tf.nest.map_structure(lambda x, y: x.assign(y), c, c_)
    loss = tf.norm(c) # scalar
print(tape.gradient(loss,c[0],output_gradients=tape.gradient(c_[0],x))+\
      tape.gradient(loss,c[1],output_gradients=tape.gradient(c_[1],x)))
# tf.Tensor(5.0932484, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Explaination:

Because tf.GradientTape is based on  the `matrix differential theory`, but will collect all  derivation of a same variable (add them to a whole) after `.gradient()`. Such as derive a `vector` with respect to `a scalar`, in matrix theory, we will get a `vector` derivation, but in `tf.GradientTape`, a `reduce_sum like` will be applied then to got a summated scalar.

Here `tape.gradient(loss,c,output_gradients=tape.gradient(c_,x))`
acctually did:

```py
tape.gradient(loss,c[0],output_gradients=tape.gradient(c_,x)[0]),
tape.gradient(loss,c[1],output_gradients=tape.gradient(c_,x)[1])

but 
tape.gradient(c_,x)[0] != tape.gradient(c_[0],x)
tape.gradient(c_,x)[1] != tape.gradient(c_[1],x)
```

So `tape.gradient(loss,c,output_gradients=tape.gradient(c_,x))` contrary to our original intention.

- For the more sophisticated issue:
  `jacobian` is needed

```py
import tensorflow as tf

tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed(0)
a = [tf.Variable(tf.random.normal(shape=[2])),tf.Variable(tf.random.normal(shape=[1])),tf.Variable(tf.random.normal(shape=[]))]
b = [tf.Variable(tf.random.normal(shape=[2])),tf.Variable(tf.random.normal(shape=[1])),tf.Variable(tf.random.normal(shape=[]))]
c = [tf.Variable(tf.random.normal(shape=[2])),tf.Variable(tf.random.normal(shape=[1])),tf.Variable(tf.random.normal(shape=[]))]
x = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal(shape=[]), name='x')

with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
    c_ = tf.nest.map_structure(lambda _a, _b: (1-x)*_a+ x*_b, a, b)

    tf.nest.map_structure(lambda x, y: x.assign(y), c, c_)

    loss = tf.norm(tf.nest.map_structure(lambda e: tf.norm(e), c))
    loss_without_assign = tf.norm(tf.nest.map_structure(lambda e: tf.norm(e), c_))

print(loss, loss_without_assign)
print(tf.reduce_sum([
    tf.reduce_sum(tape.jacobian(c_[0],x)*tape.gradient(loss,c[0])),
    tf.reduce_sum(tape.jacobian(c_[1],x)*tape.gradient(loss,c[1])),
    tf.reduce_sum(tape.jacobian(c_[2],x)*tape.gradient(loss,c[2]))
    ]))
# tf.Tensor(0.7263656, shape=(), dtype=float32)
print(tape.gradient(loss_without_assign, x))
# tf.Tensor(0.7263656, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Thanks for the remark about `output_gradients`! May I ask how it would be possible to get a 1D gradient for a scalar variable `x` representing the weighted sum `(1-x)*a + x*b` where `a` and `b` represent a list of variables? I edited my question and added my attempt.

Comment: @user19087072 I have extended the above answer and you can check it.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot for the clear explanation ! The last thing I am wondering about is the following situation: `a = [tf.Variable([1.0, 2.0]), tf.Variable([3.0]), tf.Variable(4.0)]` and `b` and `c` similar. Is the assumption correct that `.gradient()` then applies `reduce_mean` first on each derivative and then `reduce_sum` to get to the summated scalar?

Comment: @user19087072 You'd better do not use `reduce_mean` when get your wanted gradient. Because we should be mathematically correct before we get the gradient. Taking each tf.Variable as the minimum derivation object unit, when we take derivatives in mathematics, we actually only perform "*" and "+"  according to the chain rule. `reduce_mean`  will have the risk that destroy weight balance among variables.  `.gradient()` have automatically completed the mathematical process, but since you need to assign values to variable,  cutting off the chain derivation, the above manual process code is required

Comment: Unfortunately I am still unable to reproduce the target (edited my question again). I understand the notion of the balance along variables. How should I do the aggregation of the gradients in that step? I tried (trial and error, because I am probably lacking mathematical insight) `reduce_prod` as well.

Comment: @user19087072 For your  more sophisticated issue, `jacobian` is needed. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the additional information! I gave it a try, but now I managed to get stuck again with the gradients of `b` in the sophisticated issue. `tape.gradient(loss_without_assign, b)` is what I would like, but I end up with `InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 2 values, but the requested shape has 1 [Op:Reshape]`. Some more trying leads to this assumption `tape.jacobian(c_[0],b[0])*tape.gradient(loss,c[0])`. This seems to do the trick. I'll experiment with the `tf.random.normal` to verify this.

Comment: My previous comment works when `tf.reduce_sum(tape.jacobian(c_[0],b[0])*tape.gradient(loss,c[0]), axis=0)` is used. Only problem is that with the last one the shape is `()` hence an error raises as no dimension is available. I think I will try to wrap the single value into a 1D vector because I cannot think of a 'automated' way with `tf.nest.map_structure`. Thanks again for the comments! :)